# main git repository got deleted, can I re-create it from a .git directory?

Tags: git

I had a big project with lots of branches and stuff in my git repository.

the remote git repository got deleted, all I have left is the .git I have from cloning it. can I create for it a main git repository again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.
Just add second remote say **origin2** and push to it.
For example:

```
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/user/repo.git
git push origin2 --tags --all
```

Comment: thanks. did it push all my branches as well? now when I try to clone the newly created repository I get warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout. and it provides a .git directory with no sources, and I can't switch branches

Comment: Yeah adding `--all` as an option helps.